# locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation does not stop location updates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

So I'm currently writing an app that keeps track of you while you run. I am having an issue in that when i ask the locationmanager to stopUpdatingLocation the app still continues to update the location.

```
  @IBAction func stopRunning(_ sender: UIButton) {

    mapView.showsUserLocation = false
    locationManager!.stopUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false
    locationManager = nil

    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil

    if self.playa.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.playing{
        self.playa.stop()
    }


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "tosummary", sender: self)
}
```

As you can see I have tried also setting the manager to nil which is still not working. I have tried running this code in viewWillDisappear, prepareforsegue and in the function connected the stop button.

Comment: As you don't need the location manager anymore. So, set the location manager delegate `nil` before deallocating or stoping the location manager and then try it.

Comment: make sure your code creates single instance of locationManager